# paying for ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

At installation I blew off paying thinking it would be easy to do that later.  Now I can't find a link back to the payment.  Several questions relate to method of payment and the answers start with the assumption that you're in the payment dialog.  Because of all the altruism, searching on words like "donate" and "contribute" is pretty futile.  I wanted to base the amount on how well several things like display setup worked.  Delighted with everything except how hard it is to find the payment dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It is in 'Download' section.
Is [**THIS**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=14.04.2&architecture=amd64) you were looking for?

Comment: exactly, except that if you had included an actual url it would have been helpful.  From http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop is there a link or button I'm missing to get to the payment dialog without downloading again?

Comment: I gave an actual url. If you just press "Download" at your url, you'll get to that page.

Comment: So your original answer reworded as it would be most useful to me: "At ubuntu.com/download/desktop, click the "Download" button.  If you are doing this from google chrome running on a successfully installed ubuntu, it will take you to a url like http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=14.04.2&architecture=amd64 where you can pay without actually downloading."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this link?

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute

It gives you gauges that you can use to communicate to the Ubuntu developers which part of the OS you liked the most.